# RVIZ unable to load libdefault_plugin.so

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After I tried running motion planning example for PR2 robot , there is a problem with my RVIZ that it is unable to load libdefault_plugin.so and thus when I click add , an empty panel appears and I am unable to add any display type .e.g camera.

Exact error at the terminal when I launch RVIZis as follows ;
"

- [ERROR] [1349764334.800506677]:
  wxWidgets Error
  [/opt/ros/electric/stacks/robot_model/colladadom/lib/libcollada15dom.so:
  undefined symbol:
  _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE]
  [ERROR] [1349764334.800632354]:
  Unable to load library
  [/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz/lib/libdefault_plugin.so]

"
I shall be thankful if any one could guide me to get out of this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43498/rviz-unable-to-load-libdefault_plugin.so/) by [BUTT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2372/butt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-10**:
What versions of ROS / OS are you using?

**Comment by [BUTT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2372/butt/) on 2012-09-10**:
I am using ROS Electric and Ubuntu 11.10.

**Comment by [BUTT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2372/butt/) on 2012-10-08**:
this didnt help.I was onto some other work but now again need rviz and stuck with the same error when I run rviz.Have tried reinstalling ros-electric-visulaization package and robot_model too.Any ideas to above error ;

[ERROR] [1349764334.800506677]: wxWidgets Error [/opt/ros/electric/stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check if you have compiled version of *colladadom*.

```
roscd colladadom
ls lib/
```

if the lib/ directory is empty try to recompile the package

```
rosmake colladadom
```

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0